# Progress OpenEdge: How determine if user is filling fill-in with space of empty string?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

How can I determine, in Progress OpenEdge 4GL,
if user is filling fill-in with space of empty string (on leave of fill-in)?

Answer (score 3):

In ABL, empty strings and strings of blanks are equal. So to check for "truly" empty strings, use the `length()` function.

You can use this with the `screen-value` attribute of fill-ins.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on why you care about this, another approach would be to TRIM() the fill-in before using it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

if trim(fill-in:screen-value) = "" then....

Or:

if length(trim(fill-in:screen-value)) = 0 then....